# 1st derivative of $\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$

Tags: calculus

Another simple question that I can't work out today, yet I would work it out two weeks ago!

I need to find the 1st derivative of $$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$$.

So I use the Quotient rule and I get: $$\frac{(x^2 + 1)^.5 (2) - (2x)(0.5x^2 + 0.5)^-5}{x^2+1}$$

Am I heading in the correct direction and do I just need to multiply and try to get rid of the exponents somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerator is not quite right. We want $(x^2+1)^{1/2}(2)-2x g'(x)$ where $g(x)=(x^2+1)^{1/2}$. That derivative will be $(2x)(1/2)(x^2+1)^{-1/2}$.

The denominator is right. Now you can if it is useful do some manipulation ("simplification").

**Remark:** For square roots, I think you will find $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ easier and safer to work with than the exponent notation. For other roots, the advantage goes over to the exponent notation.

Comment: Great thank you, and to simplify I should bring down the  $(x^2 + 1)^-.5$ and cancel.  How would leaving the square roots as they are be easier?

Comment: BTW I noticed my small slip in the multiplication

Comment: @user2352274: In the numerator, we get, in your notation, $2(x^2+1)^{0.5}-2x^2(x^2+1)^{-0.5}$. Multiplying this by $\frac{(x^2+1)^{0.5}}{(x^2+1)^{0.5}}$ we get $\frac{2}{(x^2+1)^{0.5}}$. Combine with the denominator. As to why use $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ notation, my feeling is that it is more visual.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\right)'=\frac{(2x)'(\sqrt{x^2 + 1})-(\sqrt{x^2 + 1})'2x}{(\sqrt{x^2 + 1})^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I read your notation correctly, but it looks like there's a mistake in the numerator:

$$f(x)=2x,\quad f^{\prime}(x)=2,\quad g(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1},\quad g^{\prime}(x)=
\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

And the numerator should then be $f^{\prime}(x)g(x)-f(x)g^{\prime}(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Without messing up with nominator and denominators:

$x=\tan { u } $ then draw right triangle, see

$\\ \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { x^{ 2 }+1 }  } =\cos { u } \\$

$\\ \frac { x }{ \sqrt { x^{ 2 }+1 }  } =\sin { u } \\$

$ \frac { du }{ dx } =\frac { 1 }{ x^{ 2 }+1 } \\$

$ f=\frac { 2x }{ \sqrt { x^{ 2 }+1 }  } =2\sin { u } \\$

$$ f'\quad =2\cos { u } \frac { du }{ dx } =\frac { 2 }{ \sqrt { x^{ 2 }+1 }  } \frac { du }{ dx } =\frac { 2 }{ \sqrt { x^{ 2 }+1 }  } \frac { 1 }{ x^{ 2 }+1 } $$